# Source Selection for multiple ENI Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, subnet, network-interface

An AWS Lambda can be network-attached to multiple subnets of a VPC.  For each attached subnet (and security group) the Lambda will have (at least) one [ENI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html).

When a Lambda, which has more than one subnet/ENI attachment, initiates traffic to a destination in the same VPC, **what rules determine which subnet/ENI is chosen for the initiated traffic**?

AWS could perhaps choose a subnet randomly from the attached subnets/ENI's.  If so, it would work fine because of the "local" default route for a VPC doesn't care about the originating subnet.  But is it random?

Recently [AWS has overhauled Lambda subnet/ENI attachments](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-improved-vpc-networking-for-aws-lambda-functions/) to become more efficient...so that a minimum of ENI's are created and re-used, rather than a new ENI per Lambda execution.  But this doesn't change the question.  Fundamentally any Lambda that is attached to multiple subnets will require that (one ENI in) one of the attached subnets is chosen for intra-VPC traffic generated by the lambda.

What are the rules for the how that subnet is chosen?

Comment: All of the subnets to which a Lambda function is attached should be configured identically (except for the AZ) so it isn't clear to me why the ENI selection for any given invocation would be of interest to you, not to mention the fact that multiple concurrent Lambda invocations often shared the same ENI even under the old network model -- this is definitely true when they are configured with a 1.5 GB memory allocation or less, and may be true in cases when the memory allocation is more, particularly with the recent enhancememt.  Can you elaborate on why you need to know?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the sensible option for AWS is to choose the ENI that is within the same subnet as the destination endpoint that the function will interact with.  This will avoid the overhead of routing no matter how minimal that overhead will be.  If the lambda function is not attached to the same subnet as the destination endpoint, then the subnet selection is likely random or some undocumented method.  I imagine running a few experiments will give you the answer.

Comment: You said `if the lambda is not attached to the same subnet as the destination endpoint, then the selection is likely random...experiment for the answer`.  I won't trust any experiments that I run.  If my results seem random..are they?  If they seem to follow a pattern, does that tell me the complete pattern?

Comment: Fair enough.  That kind of information, if it is not in the documentation (and it appears not to be based on my research), is implementation specific.  Perhaps create an AWS support ticket?

Comment: @AshamanKingpin there is *zero* overhead in routing between subnets within a VPC.  The entire network is software-defined, and the default gateway is not a real router.

Comment: Yup, I get that, but even if it is software-defined, the code path for performing the routing logic is executed unnecessarily which will consume some CPU cycles (admittedly small).